# Read cell Contents Dynamic JS/Jquery table

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html, python-3.x

I am using JS/Jquery to dynamically add rows to by Table. Here is a template that I found online:

```
<table id="tblCustomers" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtCountry" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="Add()" value="Add" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

From what I gather, in order to ensure that the actual cell content values get passed on Post I need to assign them to hidden fields.

How do I read the actual contents of the cells. 
I tried:

```
$("#submitForm").click(function(){
    alert("submit Clicked");
    $('#tblCustomers tfoot td').each(function() {        
    var cellText = $(this).html();    
});
});
```

however, All I got was this as return value: [image]

Can you let me know what I need to do to get actual value of cell.

I need to make a dynamic table/item list and i would like to send the list of items back to server for processing. Sort of like a purchase list etc..

BTW: the backend is Django 2.0

Thanks for your help. 
Tanmay

Comment: Are you wanting to send this data to the server by form submit or ajax?

Comment: Form Submit. Since I have other elements that need to go as well.

Comment: Then simply make sure your input element have a name.  They must have a name, and not be disabled, to be sent across on a form submit.

Comment: I am not sure if the question is unclear, however the table rows are dynamically added using the + or row insert. The input text elements have correct name.

Comment: The example html you gave above, none of the inputs have a name attribute on them.